# Batch command to move files to two locations

Tags: batch-file

How do I move files from one location (source), to two locations (target1 and target 2) ?

I have written a batch below, but it moves only to the folder, target1, and not the second folder, target2.

@echo off
move /-y "c:\source*.wav" "c:\target1\"
move /-y "c:\source*.wav" "c:\target2\"

Please help.

Comment: If you *move* a file from the source to target 1, what do you think is left in the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to copy to the first location, then move to the second. Once you move to the first location, there is no original source file to move to the second!

```
copy /y "c:\source*.wav" "c:\target1\" && move /y "c:\source*.wav" "c:\target2\"
```